# Binding several ItemsControl to one ObservableCollection including visibility

Tags: wpf

In general, we can not bind multiple controls to one ObservableCollection

Is it possible to do this in the following situation?

Only one part is visible at a time

In this situation, there is a reference error twice to the same collection

How does it actually work internally? Should it not include invisible code?

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding B1Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    <!--Another code for B1-->
</Grid>

<Grid Visibility="{Binding B2Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
    <!--Another code for B2 -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: What is the reference error you are referring to? Can you show us the actual error code / stacktrace?

Comment: You saw an error you did not understand, and you made up a guess about what the cause was. That isn't good practice: The guess was wrong; the issue has nothing to do with what you think. What would help us to help you is a) the full and exact text of the error message, and b) a minimal but complete code example which reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Elements is, and I don't know where you're headed using a grid for the itemspanel of your itemscontrol.

But.

You can bind to the same observablecollection multiple times.

In the code below the two visibility properties are Boolean and the converter translates true into Visibility.Visible and false into Visibility.Collapsed.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return people; }
        set { people = value;  RaisePropertyChanged();}
    }
    private bool b1Visible = true;

    public bool B1Visible
    {
        get { return b1Visible; }
        set { b1Visible = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private bool b2Visible = true;

    public bool B2Visible
    {
        get { return b2Visible; }
        set { b2Visible = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Chesney", LastName = "Brown" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Gary", LastName = "Windass" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Liz", LastName = "McDonald" });
        People.Add(new Person { FirstName = "Carla", LastName = "Connor" });
    }
}
```

My markup:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding B1Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <!--Another code for B1-->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding B2Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Both itemscontrols are visible and so I see the list of names twice.